# Find what number it used to be before element reset

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Given an array with any size, in my case the array size is **5**.

This array contains ALL numbers from 1 to 5 (must contain all of them)

```
[1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5]
 0   1   2   3   4
```

And now, one element was reset and was set to **0**, and the mission is to find what number it used to be before it turned 0.

So I have this simple solution:

**Explained:** First, loop from 1 to 5, create an inner loop to check if the `i` from the first loop exists in the whole array, if it doesn't exist, that means that it is the value it used to be before 0, because the array contained all numbers from 1 to 5 or 1 to 100 (doesn't matter) and there's on'y one rested element.

Code:

```
    int[] numbers = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    numbers[1] = 0;

    int lost = -1;

    loop: 
    for (int i = 1; i <= numbers.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
            if (numbers[j] == i) {
                continue loop;
            }
        }
        lost = i;
        break loop;
    }

    System.out.println(lost);
```

That solution is not bad, but I think there's a better solution, something more stable.

I have thought about it mathematically, in our example:

```
1 + x + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
x = 2
```

Mathematically, it's really easy. Is there a way this can be done in a programming language as easy as it is mathematically?
Any better algorithms you can think of to solve this question?

Comment: Are you identifying one number that was reset?

Comment: The sum that you mentioned works great for number that get set to zero.  You are effectively subtracting that element.  Obviously this only works for replacing a single numeric element with 0.

Comment: If you just convert the mathematical pseudocode you have into normal code, you would just calculate the total sum you are expected beforehand (size of array * (size of array + 1) / 2) and then loop through the array, summing up all the values. This should just be O(N) if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: is your array always going to be consecutive numbers starting from 1 ?

Comment: @Amit.rk3 yes  from 1

Comment: Then am not sure why we need any logic. (Index of 0)+1 should give you your answer.

Comment: @Amit.rk3 Thought u asked if it only starts from 1, sorry, my bad :/

Comment: @BenBeri That's what I thought it couldn't be that straight forward. If it was , it was no question :) anyways removed the answer in that case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for ONE element being reset.  Just subtract each remaining element from the sum and what ever is left over would have been the previous number the element was before it was reset.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int sum = 15;
    int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    numbers[4] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        sum -= numbers[i];
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Results:

> 5

Answer (score 0):

There is one more possibility, you can use HashMaps!
you don't have to traverse through any "for loops" then.

You can use Hashmaps to check whether is there any value for the key of "0", if yes then that is the case where some number is reset to 0. 
Then you can traverse the Hashmap and compare which value is missing.

Everything is done With O(1) complexity and worst case of O(n) complexity.

Comment: Best-case is `O(1)`, but average-case and worst-case are still `O(n)`. Moreover, the problem states you're given an array. Your solution would need to map the array values into a HashMap. So it's worse than a single for-loop.

Comment: @Synergist yup which is <= other solutions. 
My answer is just an alternate solution to this question.